# Asp.net Core code based policy needs access to Authorize attribute

Tags: security, asp.net-core

In my multitenant application user permissions (read Roles if you are more comfortable with that) are set per tenant so we are adding claims to each user with value *TenantName*:*Permission*.

We are using policy based authorization with custom code using the following code

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class PermissionAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public Permission[] AcceptedPermissions { get; set; }

    public PermissionAuthorizeAttribute()
    {

    }

    public PermissionAuthorizeAttribute(params Permission[] acceptedPermissions)
    {
        AcceptedPermissions = acceptedPermissions;
        Policy = "RequirePermission";
    }
}

public enum Permission
{
    Login = 1,
    AddUser = 2,
    EditOtherUser = 3,
    EditBaseData = 6,
    EditSettings = 7,
}
```

With the above code we decorate Controller actions

```
[PermissionAuthorize(Permission.EditSettings)]
public IActionResult Index()
```

In startup.cs we have

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("RequirePermission", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new PermissionRequirement()));
    });
```

The AuthorizationHandler would in this case need access to the PermissionAuthorizeAttribute so we can check what permissions were specified on the action. At the moment we can get the attribute with the below code, but I think there must be an easier way, since there is a lot of casting an iterating there.

```
public class PermissionRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<PermissionRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement)
    {

        var filters = ((FilterContext)context.Resource).Filters;

        PermissionAuthorizeAttribute permissionRequirement = null;
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            var authorizeFilter = filter as AuthorizeFilter;
            if (authorizeFilter == null || authorizeFilter.AuthorizeData == null)
                continue;

            foreach (var item in authorizeFilter.AuthorizeData)
            {
                permissionRequirement = item as PermissionAuthorizeAttribute;
                if (permissionRequirement != null)
                    break;
            }

            if (permissionRequirement != null)
                break;
        }

        //TODO Check that the user has the required claims

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

All the examples I have found are like this, where some hardwired policy is specified in startup.cs.
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Over21",
                          policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
    }

Here you decorate you controller or action with

```
[Authorize(Policy="Over21")]
public class AlcoholPurchaseRequirementsController : Controller
```

I think the above example would be better if you could specify the age in the controller/action, like this

```
[Authorize(Policy="OverAge", Age=21)]
public class AlcoholPurchaseRequirementsController : Controller
```

Now you need to add a different policy for every minimum age.

Any ideas on how to make this efficient?

Comment: Did you consider to use Resource Based Authorization(https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html)? If you go with this approach, you can send age as resource. However in this case you couldn't use `Authorize` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Although i would use [Resource Based Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html) as i commented, there is a way to achieve your goal:

First create a custom attribute:

```
public class AgeAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Age{ get; set; }
    public AgeAuthorizeAttribute(int age)
    {
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Then write a filter provider:

```
public class CustomFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public int Order
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(FilterProviderContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(FilterProviderContext context)
    {
        var ctrl = context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        var ageAttr = ctrl.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<AgeAuthorizeAttribute>();
        if (ageAttr == null)
        {
             ageAttr = ctrl.ControllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttribute<AgeAuthorizeAttribute>();
        }
        if (ageAttr != null)
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                   .AddRequirements(new MinimumAgeRequirement(ageAttr.Age))
                   .Build();

            var filter = new AuthorizeFilter(policy);
            context.Results.Add(new FilterItem(new FilterDescriptor(filter, FilterScope.Action), filter));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally register filter provider:

```
services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IFilterProvider, CustomFilterProvider>());
```

And use it

```
[AgeAuthorize(21)]
public IActionResult SomeAction()

... or
[AgeAuthorize(21)]
public class AlcoholPurchaseRequirementsController : Controller
```

ps: not tested

Comment: Thanks for the input. Seems like about the same amount of work to get the actual attribute, so I think I'll stick with my code.